# login form validation javascript - value not present in $_POST

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to validate the form with id's username and initial_password: The HTML portion is as:

```
<form name="myform" action="includes/logincontrol.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

                                                <div class="form-group"> <!-- User ID Field -->
                                                    <label id="user_name_error" >User ID:</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control"  id="username" type="text" onfocusout ="validateUserName()"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Password Field -->
                                                    <label id="password_error">Password: </label>
                                                    <input class="form-control"  id="initial_password" type="password" onfocusout ="validatePassword()"/>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Register -->
                                                    <p id="submit-error"></p>
                                                    <hr/>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login" type="submit">Login</button>
                                                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="clearfunc()"/>
                                                    <hr/>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href = 'register_user.php'">Register</button>  
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location.href = 'changepw.php'">Change Password</button> 
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
```

Java Script:

```
                    function validateUserName() {

                        var user_name_entered = document.getElementById('username').value;

                        if (user_name_entered.length === 0) {

                            producePrompt('User empty?', 'user_name_error', 'red');
                            document.getElementById('login').disabled = true;
                            return false;


                        }

                        producePrompt('User Name OK!', 'user_name_error', 'green');
                        document.getElementById('login').disabled = false;
                        return true;

                    }
                    function validatePassword() {

                        var password_entered = document.getElementById('initial_password').value;

                        if (password_entered.length === 0) {

                            producePrompt('Password empty?', 'password_error', 'red');
                            document.getElementById('login').disabled = true;
                            return false;


                        }

                        producePrompt('Password Entered!', 'password_error', 'green');
                        document.getElementById('login').disabled = false;
                        return true;

                    }
                    function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {

                        document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
                        document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;


                    }
```

I am unable to get the elements in $_POST array. Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Your `input` elements in the form have no names, that's why they won't be submitted on POST. You need to use the `name` attribute like so: `<input class="form-control"  id="username" name="username" type="text" onfocusout ="validateUserName()"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put name at inputs, to access them with `$_POST`.

```
<input name="usernameInput" class="form-control"  id="username" type="text" onfocusout ="validateUserName()"/>

<?php 
  $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
?>
```

If you want to see if the form is submited put a name in the type submit input and try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitButton']) {
   $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
   #..etc
}
```